# Comparing two char[32] with eachother

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, char

So I am getting 2 strings from files I open and read. They are exactly the same but it doesnt seem to work this way. How would i make it work/do it differently?

This is the code:

```
FILE *file;
FILE *file2;
file = fopen("hey1.txt", "r");
file2 = fopen("hey2.txt", "r");

char line[32];
char line2[32];

while (fgets(line, 32, file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
}

while (fgets(line2, 34, file2) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", line2);
}

if (line==line2) {
    printf("The same\n");
}
else {
    printf("Not the same\n");
}
```

Comment: I hope that the `fgets(line2, 34, file2)` is a typo or you are overrunning the `line2` buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `==` to compare strings.

Use

```
strcmp()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Dont know how I missed it but I did xD